# Centering in kernel pca

Tags: python, pca, kernel-trick

Below is how I am applying kernel pca. But my data in X is not mean centered (it does not have zero mean). In this regard, is below code correct (for pca we need mean centered data...what about kernel pca)

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
scikit_pca = PCA(n_components=2)
X_spca = scikit_pca.fit_transform(X)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(7,3))
ax[0].scatter(X_spca[y==0, 0], X_spca[y==0, 1],             color='red', marker='^', alpha=0.5)
ax[0].scatter(X_spca[y==1, 0], X_spca[y==1, 1],color='blue', marker='o', alpha=0.5)
ax[1].scatter(X_spca[y==0, 0], np.zeros((50,1))+0.02,color='red')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "correct" code?  What do you intend this code to do?

Comment: Kernel PCA is equivalent to regular PCA after mapping the data into feature space (according to the kernel function). So, the input data don't need to be centered. What needs to be centered is their projections in feature space. This is performed implicitly using a transformation of the kernel matrix. This should be handled automatically by your software.